# Como formatar campo para RG com órgão emissor?

Tags: java, swing, formatação

Tenho a seguinte classe java:

```
public class TesteRG {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String  RG = "24.77.195 ssp/pb";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}.\\d{2}.\\d{3}\\s\\w{3}/\\w{2}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(RG);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Valido");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Não Valido");
    }
}
```

Ela funciona, mas quando eu chamo no frame que possui um jTextField chamado jTFRG com o seguinte código personalizado **"o problema esta aqui"**:

```
jTFRG = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
try {
    jTFRG.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter("##.##.### ###/##")));
} catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

ele só me deixa inserir números. Como eu faço para inserir uma String  igual a: **12.123.44 SSP/SP**

A parte da validação está funcioanando agora só falta inserir as letras além dos números.

Quando eu tento inserir o campo formatado só me deixa colocar números e o valor da String fica: **11.11.111 111/11**

Comment: Não entendi nada:  seu problema é com a regex ou com o campo formatado??

Comment: @DiegoF Campo formatado

Comment: Só uma dica, se o RG não for expedido pela SSP, o numero dele não vai bater nesse REGEX... Militares por exemplo, tem alguns com 3R 28300 por exemplo... ou só 2300 e etc...

Comment: @LucasEduardo Obrigado pela valiosa dica !! Não tinha pensado nisso!! É verdade pode ser emitido por vários orgãos. Por enquanto vou deixar assim, sera que existe algum design pattern para resolver isso? Valeu!!

Comment: @PenaPintada acredito que não existe um pattern pra isso ainda. Até pq cada emissor tem uma característica de numeração (podendo mesclar numero e letra). O que eu vejo é muito sistema não verificando se o RG é valido, somente o CPF, minha dica é que você valide apenas o CPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo a documentação da classe [`MaskFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html), o caracter `#` indica a entrada de apenas números, se você quer mesclar a máscara numérica incluindo letras, os caracteres de formatação válidos são `U`(transforma as letras digitadas em maiúsculas) e `L`(transforma letras digitadas em minusculas):

Tente o abaixo:

```
 MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("##.##.### UUU/UU");
 formatter.install(jTFRG);
```

Fiz um teste com esta máscara e veja o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Somente aceita números nos 7 primeiros dígitos, depois só aceita letras e converte para maiúscula.

Comment: Muito obrigadoooo! Cara , já diz o "a pressa é a inimiga da perfeição"! Olhei em todos os lugares da internet! Menos na documentação!!!

Comment: @PenaPintada acontece, as vezes eu também quebro a cabeça e o problema estava ali na minha cara, o negócio é consultar uma segunda opinião ou deixa o código pra lá por um tempo com a cabeça mais fresca kkk

Comment: @PenaPintada qual pergunta? Algum problema com o mask??

Comment: Vou fazer a pergunta formalmente e ai o senhor responde no stackoverflow!